# How to make your own model as a default in the stanfordner.jar file?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I've already done with my model but its hassle to load every time i will use it. How to create a custom jar file in stanford ner to allow single-jar deployment rather than it having to load NER models from separate files?

Comment: You should set model in command or in configuration file. I guess it is what they do in default package .